# 2 colunas simples com bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, margin

Tenho uma dúvida simples sobre bootstrap. Talvez me falte um pouco de percepção pra entender o caso. Até tenho algum domínio sobre, mas seguindo essas imagens:

[image: margin entre 2 colunas]

[image: outra representação do caso]

Sei que é uma questão simples, eu sei resolver ela com  css normalmente, mas quero saber qual a melhor forma de fazer isso com o advento do bootstrap em mente. Como essa estrutura vai ser repetida em várias partes não posso deixar o css muito rebuscado... então: Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso usando o bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 ou 4? Edite sua pergunta e coloque seu código HTML e o CSS que usou se possível.

Comment: Na versão 4, muito obrigado pela resposta. me ajudou muito =D

Comment: Cara na versão 4 então é ainda melhor pq Grid é em Flex. Na documentação tem algumas classes nativas do framework que tb podem te ajudar a alinhar as coisas com Flex. Apesar que para aso Col eu prefiro o offset mesmo. Boa sorte com o projeto []´s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Bootstrap 4 e no 3 também, vc pode usar o `offset` para ajustar a div no centro do `cointainer`.

**Bootstrap 4**

Repara que bastou colocar `offset-2` na primeira div e deu certo. (veja que com isso eu tenho 2 + 4 + 4 + 2, vc tb poderia fazer 3+3+3+3 colocando `col-3 offset-3` na primeira div, só lembre-se que no máximo pode somar 12 ok) Aqui está a documentação oficial sobre o offset, vai te ajudar a entender o conceito. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
div[class^="col-"] {
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 offset-2">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col-4">Col 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Bootstrap 3**

Nesse exemplo eu fiz com duas colunas de 3 e 3 de `offset`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <style>
        div[class^="col-"] {
            height: 50px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">.col-md-3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```